# Improving a good suggested edit

Tags: discussion, review, edits, suggested-edits

I'm never particularly sure what to do when somebody suggests a good edit but that can be improved.

Say you suggest an edit. You fixed formatting, you fixed grammar and improved the overall quality of the post.

I as a reviewer, see this edit but see some minor areas where it can be improved. In the past I've "improved" the edit, but then realised that I just hijacked their edit and put my name on it and didn't give them rep.

This isn't fair, the editor deserved their rep, they made the greatest contribution to the edit.

In these cases what should I do? Should I approve the edit, and then add in my own edit after theirs? If I'm jumping through a review queue that would mean I would have to save the post and keep checking back for when the edit gets accepted to add my own edit.

Comment: Isn't this what the checkbox at the bottom is for? It should still give them rep if marked as helpful. The name thing is different, and since you were the *last* person to edit, your name being there makes sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As long as you leave the "This edit was helpful" checkbox checked, they will still get their rep.

[image]

If their edit is helpful but needs a minor improvement, improve it but leave the checkbox checked. Their suggestion will show in the revision history, and your edit will show as another, more recent, edit.

I recently improved [a suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3515517), while saying the suggestion was helpful. Take a look at [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20406126/revisions). Note that the user's suggested edit is listed, and my edit on top of that suggestion is also listed. Also note that the user [got their +2 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1249641/serv?tab=reputation).

Comment: If I remember correctly, their name didn't show up in the revision history at all. I don't remember which question though

Comment: @Cruncher Their name is shown, just not on the question page. See my updated answer.

Comment: Yeah, I saw your edit thanks. I'm not sure how I missed that. Maybe I did something wrong with the improve.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you uncheck "This edit was useful" the original editor is still getting the +2 reputation points.

By all means, if an edit was good but didn't go *quite* far enough, improve it.